No ping sent by MongoDB Agent in Cloud Manager
I have a MongoDB cluster with 2 mongoses, 3 configs and 3 mongods (1 shard) and I am in the process of upgrading from 4.4.29 to mongo 5.0.30 (and eventually to 7). Every VM runs on Ubuntu 16.04.
I started upgrading one of the secondary configs to 5.0.30, needed some release upgrades and went up to Ubuntu 20.04. Now, the config replica set is fine and healthy according to mongosh, the only problem is that this updated config server never pings Cloud Manager. Charts for Status and DB Stats in Cloud Manager are functioning and being updated
Notice that all the other servers are still running 4.4.29 on Ubuntu 16.04. The affected server is called mongodb-config-02.
My attempts at understanding this:

Checked firewalls in GCP and that https://api-agents.mongodb.com is reachable (it is)
Checked that all cluster nodes can reach this server
reinstalled MongoDB Agent from scratch
Removed the server from Cloud Manager and reinstalled the agent
Deleted all host mappings in Cloud Manager
Recreated the vm with Ubuntu 20.04 in fear of broken packages in the release upgrade
Checked systemctl's unit files for the agent service and its logs (everything looks ok, up and running)
Checked logs and fatal logs for monitoring, backup and automation

This is the content of /var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/automation-agent-fatal.log
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.037+0000] [.debug] [util/distros/distros.go:LinuxFlavorAndVersionUncached:136] Detected linux flavor ubuntu version 20.4
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.042+0000] [.error] [src/util/os.go:RunOSCommand:297] error running command openssl11 version : exit status 127
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.042+0000] [.debug] [src/util/openssl.go:getOpenSSLVersion:80] could not get openssl version of underlying operating system with error error running command openssl11 version : exit status 127
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.042+0000] [.debug] [util/distros/distros.go:openSSL11VersionInit:72] OpenSSL version 1.1.1 detected: false
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.159+0000] [.debug] [src/mmsserverappender/backendmmsserverappender.go:func2:355] Started BackendMmsServerAppender with postPeriod=1s
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:709] [15:43:44.168] Maintenence round completed with status={false 0 {true false 0  true true true -1 [] map[]}} in 1.755µs
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:716] [15:43:44.170] Resetting maintainTimer to 9.027s
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:709] [15:43:44.170] Maintenence round completed with status={false 0 {true false 0  true true true -1 [] map[]}} in 1.08µs
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:716] [15:43:44.170] Resetting maintainTimer to 9.81s
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:709] [15:43:44.170] Maintenence round completed with status={false 0 {true false 0  true true true -1 [] map[]}} in 764ns
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:716] [15:43:44.170] Resetting maintainTimer to 9.584s
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:709] [15:43:44.170] Maintenence round completed with status={false 0 {true false 0  true true true -1 [] map[]}} in 807ns
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:716] [15:43:44.170] Resetting maintainTimer to 9.703s
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:709] [15:43:44.170] Maintenence round completed with status={false 0 {true false 0  true true true -1 [] map[]}} in 597ns
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:716] [15:43:44.170] Resetting maintainTimer to 9.733s
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:709] [15:43:44.170] Maintenence round completed with status={false 0 {true false 0  true true true -1 [] map[]}} in 764ns
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/maintainers/externalmaintainer.go:mainLoop:716] [15:43:44.170] Resetting maintainTimer to 9.729s
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.170+0000] [.debug] [src/mmsserverappender/backendmmsserverappender.go:func4:355] BackendMmsServerAppender received flush request.  Flushing...
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.523+0000] [services.compressor.info] [monitoring/encoding.go:NewPoolingZlibCompressor:194] Starting 2 compressor handlers
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.523+0000] [services.compressor.info] [monitoring/encoding.go:NewPoolingZlibCompressor:194] Starting 2 compressor handlers
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.523+0000] [services.compressor.info] [monitoring/encoding.go:NewPoolingZlibCompressor:194] Starting 2 compressor handlers
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.523+0000] [services.compressor.info] [monitoring/encoding.go:NewPoolingZlibCompressor:194] Starting 2 compressor handlers
[2024-12-09T15:43:44Z] [fatallogger.warn] [fatallogger.go:main] 2024/12/09 15:43:44 Using ephemeral connections to the MMS Service

These are monitoring agent's logs:
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]       AgentVersion = 13.26.0.9233
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]      GitCommitHash = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]       ManagedAgent = true
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]          GoVersion = go1.22.9
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] dbStatsLatencyWarning = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]        enableMunin = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]   httpPprofEnabled = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] httpPprofHostAddress = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]          httpProxy = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] globalAuthUsername = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] krb5ConfigLocation = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]         krb5Keytab = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]      krb5Principal = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]  krb5RenewInterval = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]       logBatchSize = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] logNetworkInterval = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]       pollInterval = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]        dialTimeout = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]    dialWaitTimeout = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] sslRequireValidServerCertificates = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] sslRequireValidMMSServerCertificates = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] sslTrustedServerCertificates = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]        httpsCAFile = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] sslClientCertificate = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] sslClientCertificateSubject = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] sslServerClientCertificate = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] useSslForAllConnections = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]  gssapiServiceName = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] maxProfilingEntries = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]         mmsBaseUrl = https://api-agents.mongodb.com
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0]            logFile = /var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/monitoring-agent.log
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] maxLogFileSizeBytes = 1048576000
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] maxLogFileDurationHrs = 24
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] useWindowsEventLog = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.725+0000] [header.info] [::0] zlibCompressionLevel = <unset>
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.726+0000] [agent.info] [monitoringexecutor/executor.go:Execute:102] Starting monitoring module
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.726+0000] [services.compressor.info] [monitoring/encoding.go:NewPoolingZlibCompressor:194] Starting 2 compressor handlers
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.726+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:NewOnlineAgent:358] Creating generic consumer pool with a limit of 8 consumers
[2024-12-09T15:43:44.728+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:Run:324] Sleeping for 2s before starting monitoring...
[2024-12-09T15:43:46.786+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:Iterate:216] Received new configuration: Assigned 1 out of 8 plus 0 chunk monitor(s)
[2024-12-09T15:43:46.787+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:syncStatusMonitors:129] Starting monitoring of `mongodb-config-02:27017`
[2024-12-09T15:43:46.787+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:func3:311] Done. Sleeping for 87s...
[2024-12-09T15:43:46.789+0000] [metrics.dbstats.collector-mongodb-config-02:27017.info] [monitoring/collector.go:looper:246] Starting `DB stats` collection with 20 minute(s) interval, following an initial 17 minute(s) pause to stagger collection across hosts.
[2024-12-09T15:43:46.827+0000] [metrics.dbstats.collector-mongodb-config-02:27017.info] [monitoring/dbstats.go:Collect:41] Collecting DB stats for 3 database(s)
[2024-12-09T15:45:13.603+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:Iterate:216] Received new configuration: Assigned 1 out of 8 plus 0 chunk monitor(s)
[2024-12-09T15:45:13.603+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:func3:311] Done. Sleeping for 86s...

And sometimes on the other two servers something like this will be logged in monitoring agent:
[2024-12-09T15:43:28.280+0000] [agent.warn] [monitoring/agent.go:syncStatusMonitors:117] Stopping monitoring of `mongodb-config-03.c.gcpprojectname.internal:27017` which is no longer assigned.
[2024-12-09T15:43:28.280+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:syncStatusMonitors:129] Starting monitoring of `mongodb-config-02:27017`
[2024-12-09T15:43:28.280+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:func3:311] Done. Sleeping for 87s...
[2024-12-09T15:43:28.280+0000] [metrics.dbstats.collector-mongodb-config-02:27017.info] [monitoring/collector.go:looper:246] Starting `DB stats` collection with 20 minute(s) interval, following an initial 12 minute(s) pause to stagger collection across hosts.
[2024-12-09T15:43:46.316+0000] [metrics.dbstats.collector-mongodb-config-02:27017.info] [monitoring/dbstats.go:Collect:41] Collecting DB stats for 3 database(s)
[2024-12-09T15:44:55.345+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:Iterate:216] Received new configuration: Assigned 1 out of 8 plus 0 chunk monitor(s)
[2024-12-09T15:44:55.345+0000] [agent.warn] [monitoring/agent.go:syncStatusMonitors:117] Stopping monitoring of `mongodb-config-02:27017` which is no longer assigned.
[2024-12-09T15:44:55.345+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:syncStatusMonitors:129] Starting monitoring of `mongodb-config-03.c.gcpprojectname.internal:27017`
[2024-12-09T15:44:55.345+0000] [agent.info] [monitoring/agent.go:func3:311] Done. Sleeping for 87s...

Anybody has any idea of what may be happening?
I've been running in circles for too long and I may end up recreating the whole cluster and do a mongosync if I can't revive the agent and ping
